# Using interfaces as method parameters in C# or vb.net

Tags: vb.net, interface

How to pass a object that is initialized from a derived class to a method that has Interface as the parameter? Below is the example of what I'm trying. Is it possible? Please suggest any better way of doing.

```
Public Interface IFruit
    Property Name As String
    Property Color As String
End Interface



Public Class Fruit
    Implements IFruit
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Color As String

    Public Property Color As String Implements IFruit.Color
        Get
            Return _Color
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Color = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String Implements IFruit.Name
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Class FruitExtended
    Inherits Fruit

    Private _Taste As String
    Public Property Taste() As String
        Get
            Return _Taste
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Taste = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class A

Public Sub ProcessFruit(F as IFruit)
'...
'Do something
End Sub
```

will the below code work? or how to achieve this in other ways?

```
Public Sub Test()
   Dim F1 as new FruitExtended()
   ProcessFruit(F1)
End sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did you try it? Would only take a few seconds to have gotten the answer yourself.

Comment: I'd advice to do: `Dim F1 As IFruit = New FruitExtended()`

Comment: Thanks, got it. Suppose if I have a class implemented from two interfaces (say A,B) how to define a generic method with interface as the parameter? I mean what should be the type of param (should it be A or B) in that method?

Comment: If a method only needs to use one of the interfaces, the parameter should generally be of that type.  If many methods will need both, and you control the code of classes implementing the interfaces, define a new interface which inherits the first two but doesn't add any new members, and have your class implement that.  Then use that new interface as the parameter type.  If a method will need objects that happen to implement two interfaces, but don't share any common class or interface, there are ways of handling that, but they're more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your code, but - in general - interfaces are good because they define a *behaviuor* rather than a state (properties). So maybe you could rethink your design and ask yourself what the ProcessFruit is supposed to do with a IFruit.

Some languages even disallow to declare properties in interfaces, other than constants. Java is an example.